# Are there "professional" single input external sound cards?

Tags: audio-interfaces

I do not need something as advanced as the PreSonus FireStudio 26x26, which can handle up to 26 inputs simultaneously. For me a one/two inputs sound card is enough. However, I do want the same level of quality and amount of features as I would get from a high end card like the one mentioned above. In other words, I want a very advanced low end card. Do these things exist? Or do I have to buy one of the over kill ones? What are some external sound cards that fit this description?

Answer (score 5):

Can you be more specific about the specific features you need?

The quick answer is the [Apogee One and Duet](http://apogeedigital.com/products/). They are more expensive than a used MOTU 828 mk2, but have a stellar reputation.

There are also plenty of high quality single channel USB interfaces designed for plugging into a single microphone. The [Blue Icicle](http://bluemic.com/icicle/) comes to mind immediately, 
but you are probably better off browsing the products at a place like [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ns=p_PRICE_2%7C0&ci=14834&N=4294550051&srtclk=sort).

Comment: Yep, what he said :)  Another place to look is the USB interfaces over at Sweetwater.   The [$100-$500](http://www.sweetwater.com/c695--USB_Audio_Interfaces/low2high/params=eyJkaW1lbnNpb24iOnsiUHJpY2UgUmFuZ2UiOlsiOSIsIjgiLCI3Il19fQ) range includes a number of reputable names.

Comment: Yeah, Sweetwater is nice too. But it is easier to get a direct flight from Haifa to NYC for some gear shopping :)